# Problems compiling apps with differing GTK versions

Tags: gtk, ubuntu-16.04, gtk3, gtk2

I am on Elementary OS 0.4.1/Ubuntu 16.04 build

I noticed that while building apps with Gtk, the outputs of Gtk2 and Gtk3 are different.
As a demonstration, here is a simple hello world app in C with the same window size declared as `350,500` but executed differently.
[image]

As you can see, the background window is with Gtk2 and the foreground smaller window is Gtk3.
They both are different. They window sizes should have been similar.

This really messes up code in python or ruby bindings for gtk, while writing gtk apps. Most of the behavior is unpredictable. Toolkits relying on gtk3 package the app with weird looking window layouts as compared to toolkits with gtk2.

Gtk2 code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 350, 500);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Gtk3 code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 350, 500);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

My gtk versions

```
$> apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
libgtk2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Candidate: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 500
        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.24.30-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libgtk-3-0:
  Installed: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
  Candidate: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 500
        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.9-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ubuntu.ipserverone.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: did you compile your "gtk2" code against Gtk3? If you do so, you will check that the resulting window is similar. Gtk2 still exists due to legacy. Don't use Gtk+ 2.x on new software. What is the question anyway?

Comment: The size are the same according to my test. https://imgur.com/a/feSX4PU. Compiled with gtk version 2.24.32 and 3.22.30.

Comment: @JoséFonte Compiling the gtk2 code with gtk3 lib does not result in same window size. This is the problem, in my setup gtk3 is not behaving properly. The gtkinspector shows it has reserved space for a larger window size, but what is actually shown is smaller, like in the image. There is something wrong with gtk3. I can't debug what.

Comment: @JohnKoch Yeah your setup works properly without surprises. But not in my case. Gtk2 is good but not gtk3.